# Should data load occur in model or viewmodel when using Knockout

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Is it wise to put your ajax calls in your Knockout ViewModel or should it instead be placed in a Model?  I've come up with a few approaches but none feel completely right.

**Approach 1 - ViewModel Only**

```
window.someDataVM = function() {
   var self = this;

    //used to enable loading indicator
    self.pendingLoad = ko.observable(true);

    self.myData = ko.observableArray();

    self.load = function() {
        //make ajax call and populate myData observable array
    }     
}
```

*Advantages*

- Simplest code structure - easier to maintain

*Disadvantages*

- No reuse for data retrieval

**Approach 2 - Model and ViewModel With Callback**

```
   window.someDataVM = function() {
       var self = this;

        //used to enable loading indicator
        self.pendingLoad = ko.observable(true);

        self.myData = ko.observableArray();

        self.load = function() {            
            someDataM.load(function(data) {
                //populate myData observable array
            });
        }     
    }

    window.someDataM = function() {
       return {               
          load: function(callback) {
             //get data via ajax and return via callback
          }
       }
    }
```

*Advantages*

- More code reuse on data retrieval (i.e. one place to load someData)
- Simpler interface that approach 3

*Disadvantages*

- Uses callbacks

**Approach 3 - Model and ViewModel With Knockout Model**

```
window.someDataVM = function() {
       var self = this;

        //used to enable loading indicator
        self.pendingLoad = ko.observable(true);

        self.myData = ko.observableArray();

        self.load = function() {
            someDataM.load();
        }

        someDataM.isLoaded.subscribe(function(isLoaded) {
            if (isLoaded)  {
               //populate observable array
            }
        });     
}



window.someDataM = function() {
     return {
          isLoaded: ko.observable(false);
          items: [],
          load: function() {
             //get some data, populate items, set isLoaded
          }
     }
    }();
```

*Advantages*

- Doesn't use callback
- Keeps data code centralized

*Disadvantages*

- Will be complicated to have lots of data entry points (i.e. LoadById, LoadByName, etc, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't feel comfortable with self-loading VMs. Thus, I would recommend to load data (model) first, and then pass it to the VM.

Conceptually, it would be something like this:

```
function loadData() {
    //load data, can be asynchronously. Then callback
    callback(data);
}

function callback(data) {
    var vm = new someDataVM(data);
    //do something with VM.
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
}
```

This kind of approach makes even more sense when VMs are created by other VMs (multi-screen applications). Also, this approach emphasizes on model-view-viewModel separation by making a chain of logical dependency:

```
View => ViewModel => Model
```

However, VMs can re-load data or make asynchronous calls on user interactions. e.g. user may click a button on the page which loads the current time again. These kinds of interactions will happen inside the existing vm obviously. But the question was related to initial load, which I approach this way.

Comment: So it sounds like you would recommend approach #2 with the model returning data via callback.  This makes sense to me and separates the concerns.

Comment: Not really. Your VM first initializes (gets created using new operator), and then it loads the data to populate itself. I would not do that because this will be hard to maintain when you need to have more than one vm to be created, and if they depend on each other. In my approach, data is loaded from outside the VM, so the initialized VM is ready to be used right away. To better follow, imagine chains of dependencies between VMs when all them are ready but the data is still loading. I think this is hard to manage. In other words, your question does not contain this case.

Comment: Ahh - I see what you are saying and yes that makes sense.  However - in your example the loadData code is essentially in global scope.  Would using the model load method as demonstrated in approach 2 work?  Then when initializing the app pass in the loaded data into the VM.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I tried to express with my example: first prepare model/data, and then initialize VM by passing data to it.